# Debian WSL Error : You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list

Tags: debian, vlc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to get build-dep vlc through Debian WSL in Windows 10.
In the sources.list, all I get is:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main                                                                            
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
```

Looks to me like I'm missing a couple sources, if so how can I get those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can duplicate and append the lines in sources.list with replacing `deb` with `deb-src`. Like this

```
...
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
...
```

And run `apt update` then `apt build-dep` should work.

Answer (score 1):

1. nano /etc/apt/sources.list
2. Add deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
3. Run sudo apt update.
4. To verify run: apt source libfreefare